# Mostrar números separados por comas cada 3 dígitos en django

Tags: javascript, python, css, bootstrap, django

Estoy haciendo una página con `django` y me gustaría que al mostrar números estos estén separados por comas(,).

En lugar de que aparezca

```
32145630.1
```

que aparezca

```
32,145,630.1.
```

Me podrían dar algún consejo.
Estoy usando `django 2.1`, `python 3.6.6` y `bootstrap`.

Gracias!!

Comment: por favor revisa [ask] y trata de mejorar tu publicación, añadiendo lo que haz intentado y siendo mas claro si eso lo harás con JS o con python

Comment: Lo tomaré en cuenta para la próxima. Y lo dejo abierto por que en cualquier lenguaje esta bien, ya sea en js o python o incluso en html si fuera posible, mientras funciones no importa en que parte de la página lo implemente

Answer (score 2):

[humanize](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/dev/ref/contrib/humanize/#ref-contrib-humanize) de `Django` te ayudara  en lo que necesitas:

```
{% load humanize %}
{{ numero | intcomma }}
```

Entonces:
`numero` es la variable que contiene los digitos e [intcomma](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/dev/ref/contrib/humanize/#intcomma) convierte un entero a float en una cadena que contiene comas cada tres dígitos.

Para activar estos filtros, agregua `django.contrib.humanize` a tu configuración `INSTALLED_APPS` en el archivo `settings.py`. Una vez que hayas hecho eso, utilízalo en una plantilla y tendrás acceso a los siguientes filtros;

```
{% load humanize %}
```

Comment: Vaya! pensar que era tan fácil jaja, muchas gracias!! si me funcionó